# Is there a way to know how many audio context are opened in a DOM?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm using Web Audio API and for different reasons I have to create multiple audio context. This is not an issue with Firefox or Edge, but Chrome doesn't allow more than 6 context. Since the number of contemporary context is 3 (the others are closed using close()) probably some reference in Chrome is still counted.
Is there a way to know how many Audio Contexts are associated to the DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper function –

```
function createAudioContext () {
    if ( createAudioContext.count++ >= 6 ) throw new Error('uh oh')
    return new AudioContext();
}
createAudioContext.count = 0;
```

and use it in place of `new AudioContext()`

Comment: That's not going to work for my issue. I'm pretty sure of how many AudioContext I've opened and how many them I've closed, but for some reason the browser is counting them in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Update to a more recent version of Chrome.  The limit has been removed.

Comment: Which version of Chrome would one need in order to avoid this limitation? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Looking up the change, I see that it should be in Chrome 66.0.3335.0, which is currently Chrome Dev build.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to notice some limit in Chrome in 2020, so I might consider something more like the following.

**Class Properties**

```
audioContextCount = 6;
audioContexts = new Array<AudioContext>();
```

**Create Contexts On Init**

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.audioContextCount; i++) {
  let context = new AudioContext();
  this.audioContexts.push(context);
}
```

**Grab Rotating Context Before Use**

```
let context = this.audioContexts.shift();
this.audioContexts.push(context);
```

An improvement might be to check the number of contexts supported and then use that as your basis, but above outlines the idea.

[Sound Box Demo](https://gregbrubaker.com/music)